# How to get the sum, difference, product, and quotient from a macro in ConTeXt or Plain TeX?

Tags: context, plain-tex, programming, calculations

I want to create a set of macros like this:

```
\addnumbers{2}{5}

\subtractnumbers{3}{5}

\multiplynumbers{2}{-2}

\dividenumbers{2}{8}
```

The first will display the number 7, adding `#1` and `#2`.

The second will display -2, subtracting `#2` from `#1`.

The third will display -4, multiplying `#1` by `#2`.

The last will display 4, dividing `#2` by `#1`.

I've tried searching for ways to do these calculations in ConTeXt or even Plain TeX, but since math is a common thing to display in this software, the search results just return ways to display math, not to calculate it.

How can I get these macros to do the calculations?

Comment: Are you ok with a Plain-LuaTeX solution, or does it have to be a Plain-pdfTeX solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. I'm not familiar with that. I use ConTeXt, so a ConTeXt answer or one working in TeX always works in ConText.

Comment: I tried something like `\newcount\thisisacounter{4}` then `\multiply\thisisacounter by 5` then `\ref{\thisisacounter}` and had no luck getting that to display the product of 4 and 5.

Comment: \nexcount simply creates the count (assigns a register).  Setting it is a separate step (\thisisacounter=4).  BTW, LaTeX nomenclature is that a counter is a count of the form  `\c@name` for some counter name..

Comment: The "Plain" in "PlainTeX" refers to the macros defined in the TeXbook -- collectively, a "format". The term "PlainTeX" does not specify which engine is in use: it could be pdfTeX, XeTeX, or LuaTeX. ConTeXt is a format that's built exclusively on LuaTeX; it will not work under pdfTeX. "Plain-LuaTeX", then, corresponds to the Plain *format* built on top of the LuaTeX engine.

Comment: Just to add to the comment by @Mico: Actually, ConTeXt is a format that can be built on pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX and LuaMetaTeX. MkII works on pdfTeX and XeTeX, MkIV is LuaTeX-only and LMTX is LuaMetaTeX-only. MkIV and LMTX support Lua interaction.

Comment: @TeXnician - Thanks for this. Out of idle curiosity: When did LuaTeX-only MkIV become the standard engine for ConTeXt? I’m guessing it’s been at least 5 years, and maybe even 7 or 8 years.

Comment: @Mico I have no definite number for this. But I would guess it is for at least 8 years. It has been the default in 2014 (when I made a first attempt to use it) for sure. And given the adaption rate of Hans Hagen with LuaMetaTeX (which basically replaced MkIV in large parts of his productive environment within a few weeks) I would think it has been similar with MkIV.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ConTeXt you can use the lua interface:

```
\starttext
  The first will display the number \ctxlua{context(2+5)}
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\luaexpr{2+5}` instead of `\ctxlua{context(2+5)}`.  See [ConTeXt Lua Documents](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A149%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Fit%22%7D%5D) for details.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I still prefer `\ctxlua{context(...)}` because it is possible to specify formatting specifiers: `\ctxlua(context("0.3f", 5/3)}`. Not sure how to do that using `\luaexpr`.

Comment: @Aditya You have a `\letterpercent` missing.  With `\luaexpr` you can also easily do it: `\luaexpr{string.format("\letterpercent 0.3f", 5/3)}`.  The main point of `\luaexpr` is to protect the user from a situation where the expression could evaluate to a boolean in which case it is interpreted in a special way by `context(...)`.

Comment: @HenriMenke: Ah, thanks!

Comment: @HenriMenke: Good to know 

Answer (score 19):

You can use the ε-TeX primitive `\numexpr` for expandable integer expressions. The only restriction is that it won't work in engines without ε-TeX extensions (mostly Knuth TeX nowadays), in which case you need to go with siracusa's solution.

These macros being expandable, allows you to use them anywhere TeX expects a number, like in `\ifnum`, `\ifcase`, or `\ifdim` (with the proper units) tests, register assignments, etc.

Here are the four interfaces you want (I swapped the order of the arguments in `\dividenumbers` because I think it makes more sense this way), plus a generic `\inteval`, which takes an integer expression, like `2+5*(3-4)`, as argument:

```
\def\addnumbers#1#2{\number\numexpr#1+#2\relax}
\def\subtractnumbers#1#2{\number\numexpr#1-#2\relax}
\def\multiplynumbers#1#2{\number\numexpr#1*#2\relax}
\def\dividenumbers#1#2{\number\numexpr#1/#2\relax}
\def\inteval#1{\number\numexpr#1\relax}

\def\test#1#2#3#4{$#2#3#4 = #1{#2}{#4}$\par}
\test\addnumbers{2}+{5}
\test\subtractnumbers{3}-{5}
\test\multiplynumbers{2}\times{-2}
\test\dividenumbers{8}\div{2}

$2+5\times(3-4) = \inteval{2+5*(3-4)}$
\bye
```

> [image]

If you don't want to restrict yourself to integers, you can use `expl3`'s FPU, which is format-independent, and also expandable. It allows you a much larger range of operations. The code below defines the four interfaces you asked, plus `\fpeval` for generic floating point expressions (in LaTeX the package `xfp` provides the same `\fpeval`):

```
\input expl3-generic.tex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \addnumbers #1 #2
  { \fp_eval:n { #1 + #2 } }
\cs_new:Npn \subtractnumbers #1 #2
  { \fp_eval:n { #1 - #2 } }
\cs_new:Npn \multiplynumbers #1 #2
  { \fp_eval:n { #1 * #2 } }
\cs_new:Npn \dividenumbers #1 #2
  { \fp_eval:n { #1 / #2 } }
\cs_new:Npn \fpeval #1
  { \fp_eval:n { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\def\test#1#2#3#4{$#2#3#4 = #1{#2}{#4}$\par}
%
\test\addnumbers{2}+{5}
\test\subtractnumbers{3}-{5}
\test\multiplynumbers{2}\times{-2}
\test\dividenumbers{8}\div{2}

$2^2+5\times(\cos(3)-4) = \fpeval{2^2+5*(cos(3)-4)}$
\bye
```

> [image]

Comment: AFAIK expl3 is neither plain TeX nor ConTeXt

Comment: @sztruks No. `expl3` is format-independent, so you can load it in either Plain, ContTeXt, or LaTeX (try it :-). The only requirement is a recent enough TeX engine (at least pdfTeX v1.40, XeTeX v0.99992, LuaTeX v0.95, or e-(u)pTeX mid-2012). The difference is that in LaTeX there is a dedicated package `expl3.sty` (with all the `\ProvidesPackage` things), and for ConTeXt or Plain you use the generic loader `expl3-generic.tex`. But the bulk of the code (`expl3-code.tex`) is the same for all three.

Comment: Oh, nice to know this. Thanks.

Comment: CAVEAT: Division in `\numexpr` rounds, whereas `\divide` truncates!

Answer (score 13):

As you haven't specified if the solution should be expandable, here's a non-expandable plain TeX solution.

We first define a general `\docalc` macro which takes a calculation command working on count registers (`\advance`, `\multiply` or `\divide`), and the two operands. The operation is applied on a local register which value is immediately output afterwards. Based on `\docalc` we then define the four macros for doing the basic arithmetic operations:

```
\def\docalc#1#2#3{%
    \begingroup
    \count0=#3
    #1\count0 by #2\relax
    \the\count0
    \endgroup
}

\def\addnumbers       {\docalc\advance}
\def\subtractnumbers#1{\docalc\advance{-#1}}
\def\multiplynumbers  {\docalc\multiply}
\def\dividenumbers    {\docalc\divide}

$2 + 5 = \addnumbers{2}{5}$

$5 - 3 = \subtractnumbers{3}{5}$

$2 \cdot (-2) = \multiplynumbers{2}{-2}$

$8 \div 2 = \dividenumbers{2}{8}$
\bye
```

> [image]

Comment: I'd add a `\relax` after `by #2`, since what follows is expandable (+1 though :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik This should only be an issue if `\endlinechar` had a weird value, no (as the space from it should make the scanner stop)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the reasoning for my comment. It's just nitpicking, really. For reasonable input, that should  be no problem, since the `\endlinechar` space stops scanning for an integer. However if the first number is an incomplete number (empty, for example), then the `\the\count0` is silently taken as the number. With `\relax` TeX will raise an error. Of couse it requires a weirdo trying to break your code with malicious input for that to happen ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Here's a Plain-LuaTeX solution. The arguments of `\addnumbers`, `\subtractnumbers`, etc. can be either numbers or something that evaluates to a number using simple arithmetic operations (but not exponentiation, as the meaning of `^` differs drastically between TeX and Lua). If the result of the calculations is a whole number, no decimal part is printed, courtesy of the Lua utility function `myprint` defined below.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = luatex
\directlua{% Define a utility function:
```

```lua
  function myprint (u) 
    if u==math.floor (u) then 
      tex.sprint ( math.floor (u) )
    else 
      tex.sprint (u) 
    end
  end
```

```tex
}
\def\addnumbers#1#2{\directlua{myprint((#1)+(#2))}}
\def\subtractnumbers#1#2{\directlua{myprint((#1)-(#2))}}
\def\multiplynumbers#1#2{\directlua{myprint((#1)*(#2))}}
\def\dividenumbers#1#2{\directlua{myprint((#2)/(#1))}}

$\addnumbers{8-6}{5} \quad
 \subtractnumbers{3}{6-1} \quad
 \multiplynumbers{2}{-6+4} \quad
 \dividenumbers{3-1}{4+2+4/2}$
\bye
```